# failed to lazily initialize a collection, no session or session was closed

Tags: grails, groovy, lazy-loading

I know this has been asked lot of times and I have read/tried most of the solutions I can ever find. But I can not find the exact solution to my problem. Most of them are calling the save() but I am only getting the list. This is in groovy/grails.

the error *"failed to lazily initialize a collection, no session or session was closed"* occurs when this code is executed the `return caseVisualImpairmentCauses` part. When the `caseVisualImpairmentCauses` contains value, it returns the error *"object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing".*

```
def List<CaseVisualImpairmentCause> bindVisualImpairmentCause(Long visualImpairmentPrimaryCauseId, ArrayList caseVisualImpairmentCausesList,
    String visualImpairmentOtherCause) {
    def caseVisualImpairmentCauses = []

    if (visualImpairmentPrimaryCauseId) {
        def visualImpairmentPrimaryCauseInstance = VisualImpairmentCause.get(visualImpairmentPrimaryCauseId)
        CaseVisualImpairmentCause caseVisualImpairmentPrimaryCause = new CaseVisualImpairmentCause(visualImpairmentCauseIdvisualImpairmentCause: visualImpairmentPrimaryCauseInstance)
        caseVisualImpairmentPrimaryCause.isPrimary = true
        caseVisualImpairmentCauses << caseVisualImpairmentPrimaryCause
    }
    caseVisualImpairmentCausesList.each {
        VisualImpairmentCause visualImpairmentCause = VisualImpairmentCause.get(it as Integer)
        CaseVisualImpairmentCause caseVisualImpairmentCause = new CaseVisualImpairmentCause(visualImpairmentCauseIdvisualImpairmentCause: visualImpairmentCause)
        if (it.equals('5')) {
            caseVisualImpairmentCause.caseVisualImpairmentCauseOther = visualImpairmentOtherCause
        }
        caseVisualImpairmentCauses.add(caseVisualImpairmentCause)
    }
    return caseVisualImpairmentCauses
}
```

the one calling that is

```
    obpCaseInstance.visualImpairmentCauses = caseService.bindVisualImpairmentCause(visualImpairmentPrimaryCauseId, listOfCaseVisualImpairmentCauses, visualImpairmentOtherCause)
```

any idea why this error happens?

Comment: Where are you calling this method?

Comment: because I want to get the list of visual impairments that is already in the db and the visual impairment(s) the user just checked before leaving/directing the page. The main page have several redirect(to add client , to add contact) and I need to maintain data in the process. the  this is in webflow.

Comment: any custom getters/setters in your domain classes?

Comment: I believe this is because you are instantiating new objects and not saving them before returning from the service method (end of transaction/hibernate trying to flush the instance).

Comment: i was just trying to fetch the data and I do not intend to save it until end of webflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this by changing all findbyId(), .get() and getbyId() into .read(). It appears that the methods(find, get) are already flushing and as good as calling .save(). I also took out all methods fetching data (methods that cant be replaced by .read() like findBYOtherproperty) being called from another service and put it in the same method instead. This made the error go away without me forcing to save the object first before leaving the service.